# C# / VBS Automate Team Project Creation in TFS 2015 Update 3

Tags: c#, excel, visual-studio, tfs

I'm looking for a way to automate team project creation in TFS 2015 Update 3.

I did a quick crawl over the web and found various posts on how to do it but nothing specific to 2015 version update 3.

Some links I found:
[#1](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/granth/2009/09/25/scripting-team-project-creation-in-tfs2010/)
[#2](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/granth/2009/09/25/scripting-team-project-creation-in-tfs2010/)

I'd like to do it as simple and lightweight as possible.

A rough idea would be to fill up all the details needed e.g.:
Sign in details, server, collection, project name, etc... on an excel, save the information somewhere (like an xml for presented on link#2) and trigger a batch file to do the necessary stuff via vbs macro.

To be honest I do not know where to start yet, like how to even automate the project creation part.

Appreciate if you can point me in the right path to start this out. Ideas are also welcome :). Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Do you mean a team project or team project collection? Have you read [why use single TFS Team Project](http://geekswithblogs.net/Optikal/archive/2013/09/05/153944.aspx)?

Comment: I'd like to create an (X) project at any time on any given available collections. I do not need to create collections. The assumption would be that the collections are already existing, I would simply select a collection to where I would create my team project

Comment: The whole idea is that team project should be seldom created if you read the link I gave you. So seldom that doing it manually should be fine.

Comment: It's possible. Look at the REST APIs. Before you do that, understand that the fewer team projects you have, the better -- one is usually enough.

Comment: @DanielMann, CodingYoshi, Thanks for your inputs. Unfortunately, I do not have control over how many projects are to be created. This directive is actually initiated by the project manager (the process is already in place on how the organization does it, I just need to automate this process this time) I will read the link and convey the information to the manager. For now, I'll still wait for concrete answers on how to start this. Thanks!

Comment: @iamkenos Did you try the code below and did you solved your issue?

Comment: @Tingting0929-MSFT, it took me a while but yup I managed to try this out. Thanks! However, there was a change in directive and I was asked to do it via the web browser instead. So I ended up scrapping the whole thing. Thanks though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [this REST API](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/tfs/projects#create-a-team-project) to create a team project. TFS also provide to using C# code to create a team project:

```
    public static TeamProject CreateProject()
    {

        string projectName = "Sample project";
        string projectDescription = "Short description for my new project";
        string processName = "Agile";

        VssCredentials c = new VssCredentials(new Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common.WindowsCredential(new NetworkCredential("username", "password", "domain")));
        VssConnection connection = new VssConnection(new Uri("http://v-tinmo-12r2:8080/tfs/MyCollection"),c);


        // Setup version control properties
        Dictionary<string, string> versionControlProperties = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        versionControlProperties[TeamProjectCapabilitiesConstants.VersionControlCapabilityAttributeName] =
            SourceControlTypes.Git.ToString();

        // Setup process properties    
        ProcessHttpClient processClient = connection.GetClient<ProcessHttpClient>();
        Guid processId = processClient.GetProcessesAsync().Result.Find(process => { return process.Name.Equals(processName, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase); }).Id;
        Dictionary<string, string> processProperaties = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        processProperaties[TeamProjectCapabilitiesConstants.ProcessTemplateCapabilityTemplateTypeIdAttributeName] =
            processId.ToString();

        // Construct capabilities dictionary
        Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>> capabilities = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>();
        capabilities[TeamProjectCapabilitiesConstants.VersionControlCapabilityName] =
            versionControlProperties;
        capabilities[TeamProjectCapabilitiesConstants.ProcessTemplateCapabilityName] =
            processProperaties;

        //Construct object containing properties needed for creating the project
       TeamProject projectCreateParameters = new TeamProject()
        {
            Name = projectName,
            Description = projectDescription,
            Capabilities = capabilities
        };

        // Get a client
        ProjectHttpClient projectClient = connection.GetClient<ProjectHttpClient>();
        TeamProject project = null;
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Queuing project creation...");

            // Queue the project creation operation 
            // This returns an operation object that can be used to check the status of the creation
            OperationReference operation = projectClient.QueueCreateProject(projectCreateParameters).Result;

            // Check the operation status every 5 seconds (for up to 30 seconds)
            Operation completedOperation = WaitForLongRunningOperation(connection, operation.Id, 5, 30).Result;

            // Check if the operation succeeded (the project was created) or failed
            if (completedOperation.Status == OperationStatus.Succeeded)
            {
                // Get the full details about the newly created project
                project = projectClient.GetProject(
                    projectCreateParameters.Name,
                    includeCapabilities: true,
                    includeHistory: true).Result;

                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Project created (ID: {0})", project.Id);

            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Project creation operation failed: " + completedOperation.ResultMessage);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception during create project: ", ex.Message);
        }

        return project;
    }



    private static async Task<Operation> WaitForLongRunningOperation(VssConnection connection, Guid operationId, int interavalInSec = 5, int maxTimeInSeconds = 60, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
    {
        OperationsHttpClient operationsClient = connection.GetClient<OperationsHttpClient>();
        DateTime expiration = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(maxTimeInSeconds);
        int checkCount = 0;

        while (true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(" Checking status ({0})... ", (checkCount++));

            Operation operation = await operationsClient.GetOperation(operationId, cancellationToken);

            if (!operation.Completed)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("   Pausing {0} seconds", interavalInSec);

                await Task.Delay(interavalInSec * 1000);

                if (DateTime.Now > expiration)
                {
                    throw new Exception(String.Format("Operation did not complete in {0} seconds.", maxTimeInSeconds));
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return operation;
            }
        }
    }
```